# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find library [libjsane.so]

Tags: java, applet, java.util.scanner, scanning

For triggering a usb scanner from the browser, we are using the [Twain scan plugin](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/twain-scan.html).

To make the downloaded zip work in linux the twain jar(uk.co.mmscomputing.device.twain.jar) was replaced with the [sane jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/u/Downloadukcommscomputingdevicesanejar.htm)

The java applet code was compiled without errors,but throws several run time Exceptions as shown below.

System Spec : Ubuntu 12.04 (64 bit)

Any help on this issue would be appreciated

Are there other similar(javascript/java-Applet) open source plugins available for triggering a Canon -Cr 50 scanner from the browser ?

Run time Exceptions:

```
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX(JarLib.java:40)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.load(JarLib.java:10)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.jsane.<clinit>(jsane.java:140)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.SaneScanner.isAPIInstalled(SaneScanner.java:17)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner.getDevice(Scanner.java:86)
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:58)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.load(JarLib.java:22)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.jsane.<clinit>(jsane.java:140)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.SaneScanner.isAPIInstalled(SaneScanner.java:17)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner.getDevice(Scanner.java:86)
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:58)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:59)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Scan_$2.actionPerformed(Scan_.java:111)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at     javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
^Citflux@itflux-desktop:/var/www/scannerApplet$ locate jsane.cpp
itflux@itflux-desktop:/var/www/scannerApplet$ locate libjsane.so
itflux@itflux-desktop:/var/www/scannerApplet$ javac Scan_.java
itflux@itflux-desktop:/var/www/scannerApplet$ java Scan_
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX: Could not find library [libjsane.so]
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.loadX(JarLib.java:40)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.load(JarLib.java:10)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.jsane.<clinit>(jsane.java:140)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.SaneScanner.isAPIInstalled(SaneScanner.java:17)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner.getDevice(Scanner.java:86)
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:58)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
JarLib.load
Error = java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jsane in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.util.JarLib.load(JarLib.java:22)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.jsane.<clinit>(jsane.java:140)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.sane.SaneScanner.isAPIInstalled(SaneScanner.java:17)
at uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner.getDevice(Scanner.java:86)
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:58)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Scan_.<init>(Scan_.java:59)
at Scan_.main(Scan_.java:43)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Scan_$2.actionPerformed(Scan_.java:111)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6516)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:740)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:713)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:711)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```